# question about ubuntu22.04 default partitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, 22.04

I used **Ubuntu20.04 and win10 dual OS** before and because some environment went wrong so I decided to erase all of them and **install Ubuntu22.04 only**. I have a 128GB SSD disk(sda) and 1TB regular disk(sdb). There is a question I didn't notice before but today I suddenly noticed: Before when I chose to automatically install ubuntu on sdb, I let ubuntu automatically erase that disk and did the partition, and then a prompt window reminded me that two partitions would be made: one is ESP(efi) and the other is `/`. After the installation finished, I can see my `/home/username` folder but I didn't manually created it.

**Does that mean `/` and `/home` are in the same partition by default? Or `/home` is mounted under `/`?(Q1)**

But I browsed many posts and people usually will manually mount `/` and `/home` in different partitions.

And here's my plan, I'm gonna partition sda into 3 partitions: `efi`, `swap`, `/` and keep the entire sdb mounting under `/home`. **so Q2 is: does this sound good?**(I mean, can this scheme separate my personal data, like docs, pics and data folders separate from the OS in case the OS broke so that I can easily recover my important data?)

I know this is a trivial question but please give me some help cuz I've been struggling for hours. Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: The `/home`-folder is always and must be located in `/`.It's not folders that are mounted to partitions, partitions are mounted to folders. If you mount a partition on `/home` you have your personal stored in a sepsrate partition. A swap partition is not needed.

Comment: @mook765 A lot of thanks. I see, I seem to misunderstand the concept of mounting. I wanna make sure again, when you say "The `/home`-folder is always and must be located in `/`", you mean logically located right? Any partition can be mounted to `/home`, is that correct?

Comment: yes, you got it...And / the folder `/home` is really located in `/`, logically, physically, whatever. The contents of `/home` can be located on a different partition which is mounted there.

Comment: Q2: 'Yes' a decade ago but 'No' today. If your need is easy data recovery, simply make regular backups. A great backup application is included with the stock install of Ubuntu Desktop. Use it. Separate /swap partitions were replaced by swapfiles for most users years ago. Some folks make too many partitions, and mis-size those partitions, then run out of space on one partition though most of their disk is empty -- that's your greater risk.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you big time! Your answer is very helpful. I'm gonna try it following your advice.

Comment: Might be good if one of you puts the comments in as an answer - it’s solved the OPs problems.